# Bellman-Ford Termination when there is no change on vertex weights?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

We know the bellman-ford algorithms check all edges in each step, and for each edge if,

> d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v)

then d(v) being updated such that w(u,v) is the weight of edge (u, v) and d(u) is the length of best finding path for vertex `u`. if in one step we have no update for vertexes, the algorithms terminate. with supposing this algorithms, for finding all shortest path from vertex `s` in graph G with `n` vertex after `k<n` iterate is finished, can we conclude:

1) number of edges in all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

2) weight of all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

I Think Neither the number of edges nor their total weight is limited by k-1 with the defining problem, but my TA says (1) is True. How can describe these conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part (1) is indeed true. The idea is that in $k$ steps the algorithm is only considering paths of length $k$. Indeed, you can prove by induction on $k$ that the path realizing the value of $d(v)$ after $k$ steps is at most $k$ edges long.

If the algorithm terminates after $k$ steps, then the results of the first $k-1$ steps are already optimal, hence (1).

Part (2) is indeed false, and I'm sure you can give a counterexample on your own.

---

The simultaneous version of the Bellman–Ford algorithm, referred to in part (1), has the following pseudo-code (where $d(x,y)$ is the weight of the edge connecting $x$ and $y$):

```
A[0,x,y] = ∞ for all x,y
t ← 0
do
  for all x,y:
    A[t+1,x,y] = min(A[t,x,y], { A[t,x,z] + d(z,y) : all z ≠ x,y })
  t ← t+1
while A[t,x,y] ≠ A[t-1,x,y] for some x,y
return A[t,x,y]
```

Take as an example the (undirected) graph $x - y - z - w$ (with unit weights). Here is a trace of the algorithm:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
t & A[t,x,y] & A[t,x,z] & A[t,x,w] & A[t,y,z] & A[t,y,w] & A[t,z,w] \\\hline
0 & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty \\
1 & 1 & \infty & \infty & 1 & \infty & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & \infty & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22678/discussion-between-yuval-filmus-and-maryam-panahi).